# Laravel 4: Normal PHP file include

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

When using blade in Laravel, we are able to include view file in a package with this:

```
@include("Mypackage::viewfile")
```

But, how can we do it without blade in normal php include `<?php include ?>`?

Thank you.

Comment: you can do something like this:  `echo file_get_contents('path/to/file');` though...why?

Comment: So, not possible to be done without blade template?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? if you want to include some html from another file that you do not want to be parsed by the template engine, that what I showed will work. If that is not what you are trying to do, then be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I am referring to a file in a package, the path to it may different on each installation. So, I cannot hard code the path to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with façade.

```
class Mypackage{
public static function view($file){
    return __DIR__."/../../views/".$file;
}
}
```

Then you can include file with `<?php include Mypackage::view("viewfile.php"); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php

  echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

  include 'vars.php';

 echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

  ?>
```